# Can a cronjob be written in a shell?

Tags: shell, cron, job-scheduling

I need to write a cronjob in `.sh` file. Is it possible to write a cronjob in `.sh` file?

My cronjob is

```
*/1 * * * * bash /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh
```

This cronjob will be executed once every minute.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**  According to comments by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), the variable `SHELL` may not be recognized by `cron` (depending on the version) and is not POSIX mandated.  This would make the method in the question a better option, on that account alone.

---

The cron will (attempt to) execute whatever is there. The way you have it, it will run `bash` with following arguments, thus `bash` will run your script. (Thanks to  [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in the comment.)

Or, you can tell cron to run all commands via the shell of your choice by setting the `SHELL` variable

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh
```

See `man 5 crontab` on a Linux system for a lot of detail and examples.

---

Given the questions posed in comments this seems appropriate to add.

To set up a cron job we need to make a "crontab" file.  This is done by invoking

```
crontab -e
```

The option `-e` is for "edit." The editor comes up and then you can enter the line from your question, then "save" and "quit".  Which editor comes up depends on the settings, but if you didn't do anything it will most likely be `vi`. The 'root' may need to 'allow' this capability for a user. You can view the contents of your crontab by `crontab -l`.

When the time comes the command will get executed and the script "/path/sample.sh" will run.  In that script your first line should be `#!/bin/bash`. The line you show does not go in the script, it belongs to the crontab file.  The rest of the script "sample.sh" should consist of code that `bash` shell can execute.

**NOTE** Please see (additional) comments by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for more detail and expertise.

Comment: If the `crontab` entry says "`bash /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh`", then `cron` is going to run `bash` and `bash` will run the script, and there's no question but that it will be run by bash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Is that a fine way of doing it? Somehow I am not comfortable with running bash out of crontab and would recommend setting a variable instead.  But now I realize that I don't really know why.

Comment: If it's important that it is run by `bash`, that's one reasonable way to do it.  You should also be able to use a shebang in the script: `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, but there's an outside chance that if you omit the `bash`, then `cron` does something sneaky and runs `sh -c "/abc/def/ghi/sample.sh"` and the shebang gets ignored and the script is run by `sh` instead of `bash`.  I might test; I might simply make sure by specifying `bash`.

Comment: @SravanKumarPadala: I'm suggesting that what you proposed in the question is OK — even safe if it is crucial that the script is run by `bash`.

Comment: @SravanKumarPadala  Ah, I think I see the problem.  I will edit the answer instead.

Comment: The script `/abc/def/ghi/sample.sh`, should start with `#!/bin/bash` and continue with the rest of the script. In the crontab entry, I'd put `* * * * * bash /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh`, but you can remove the word `bash` and it will almost certainly work the same. The `/1` is not necessary, though it does no particular harm if your variant of `cron` recognizes it. Likewise, the versions of `cron` I learned did not recognize `SHELL=/bin/bash` lines so I don't use such lines. POSIX doesn't mandate them. I always run a shell script, though — it sets the environment and then runs the 'real' command.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler I'll give a try.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
I've tried with above description but got no results.
The `shell` file is below
`#!/bin/bash
* * * * * /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh`

Comment: What do you mean by your 'shell file'? You need to create a job that will be run by `cron` by submitting a line containing `* * * * * /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh` to `crontab` (assuming you have no other `cron` jobs yet). The script that is run — `/abc/def/ghi/sample.sh` — should not contain the `*` line; it should contain the actions you want performed every minute. For example, it might contain the line `{ pwd; date; } > /tmp/cron.job.mine` (after the shebang line `#!/bin/bash`) to output the current directory and the date into a file `/tmp/cron.job.mine`.  You can check whether the file appears.

Comment: @SravanKumarPadala  See the updated answer.  The only thing to be in the script is `#!/bin/bash` -- the rest of what you show should be in a "crontab file".  See the update for how to produce that file.

Comment: @SravanKumarPadala make a file with your instruction say `#!/bin/bash * * * * * /abc/def/ghi/sample.sh` and save it. then put the file in `/etc/cron.d`. Make sure that your cron file permission would be 644. To monitor your cron plz run the command `tail -f /var/log/cron`